# Problema no Visual Studio 2013 XAML

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xaml, windows-phone-8-1

Os Objetos não aparecem no Visual do XAML.
[image]

Eles só aparecem se for um projeto usando Silverlight.
[image]

Mas no Emulador ao Compilar exibir normal, é ruim só pra editar Visual do Aplicativo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta para o problema é o visual studio 2015.
No visual studio 2015 o erro não ocorre mais.